# JSON Escape character of double quote prints in the string

Tags: json, vb6

I'm generating a JSON file using VB6 and one of my strings has a double quote in between. I have used the double quote escape character but now the escape character is also printing in the string, even though the JSON  is successful when I put the file in JSON formatter.

The string is:

```
"productName":"16X12 / 46/4X46 63" DRILL"
```

This string have a double quote in it when I use escape character and check it the JSON formatter , the JSON is successful but product name string becomes

```
"productName":"16X12 / 46/4X46 63\"DRILL"
```

as u can see the escape character is printing in the string before the double quote, How can I escape the double quote without printing the escape character.

I have tried with \ and \\ but every \ get prints.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you mean by "How can I escape the double quote without printing the escape character."

Comment: when I use escape character ('\') to escape the double quote, that escape character is printing in the string..u can see both the string I have given above..."productName":"16X12 / 46/4X46 63\"DRILL" in this I want the output as productName":"16X12 / 46/4X46 63"DRILL"

Comment: Why did you delete this question and then re-post it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a proper JSON string escaping implementation, e.g. try this

```
Private Function JsonEscape(sText As String) As String
    Const STR_CODES     As String = "\u0000|\u0001|\u0002|\u0003|\u0004|\u0005|\u0006|\u0007|\b|\t|\n|\u000B|\f|\r|\u000E|\u000F|\u0010|\u0011|\u0012|\u0013|\u0014|\u0015|\u0016|\u0017|\u0018|\u0019|\u001A|\u001B|\u001C|\u001D|\u001E|\u001F"
    Static vTranscode   As Variant
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim lAsc            As Long

    If IsEmpty(vTranscode) Then
        vTranscode = Split(STR_CODES, "|")
    End If
    For lIdx = 1 To Len(sText)
        lAsc = AscW(Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1))
        If lAsc = 92 Or lAsc = 34 Then '--- \ and "
            JsonEscape = JsonEscape & "\" & ChrW$(lAsc)
        ElseIf lAsc >= 32 And lAsc < 256 Then
            JsonEscape = JsonEscape & ChrW$(lAsc)
        ElseIf lAsc >= 0 And lAsc < 32 Then
            JsonEscape = JsonEscape & vTranscode(lAsc)
        ElseIf Asc(Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1)) <> 63 Or Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1) = "?" Then '--- ?
            JsonEscape = JsonEscape & ChrW$(AscW(Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1)))
        Else
            JsonEscape = JsonEscape & "\u" & Right$("0000" & Hex$(lAsc), 4)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This takes care of `"` and `\` in strings as well as `vbCrLf` and other special symbols (charcode < 32). This handles unicode characters too (charcode > 256).

Btw, you'll have to escape all user-supplied strings (either in keys or values) to prevent producing invalid JSON in all cases.

Comment: We have tried appending ('\') but the main problem is , when we check json string in the json formatter the ('\') is part of string which I don't want..the output of your function is same as what i'm doing directly in json formatter, adding('\') before the double quote

Comment: `the ('\') is part of string` on purpose. The keys/values will be de-escaped when your data in JSON format is parsed by client/consumer and in the process the back-slashes will "disappear" and `\r\n`s will become `vbCrLf`s.

Comment: thank u.. this is what I was looking for..even though I have my own function for appending ('\') i'm accepting he answer so if some one needs the info this function is very usefull(if there are ant vb6 developers left ;) )